# Multiple image upload with jquery plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, upload

I got this simple jquery plugin to upload files.

i can add multiple files, but i cant seem to write a code that saves all the files, only one..

```
var _thumb = string.Empty;    
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fuUploadThumps.FileName))
            {
                _thumb = fuUploadThumps.FileName;
                fuUploadThumps.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\img/produkter\" + _imagePath["categoryImagePath"] + "resized/thumbs/" + StripInput(_thumb));
            }
```

Can anyone help me?

**More code**

```
_objAdmin.Name = StripInput(_thumb);
_objAdmin.Connection = Session["imageConnection"].ToString();

_objAdmin.AddThumbs(_objAdmin);
```

Thats all :=)

Comment: Can you show us any more of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think jnoreiga is trying to tell you, is to request the files like you request the physical applicationpath. Just like so:

```
var hfc = Request.Files;
for (var i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
{
    var hpf = hfc[i];
    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var _thumb = hpf.FileName;
        hpf.SaveAs(
            Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\img/produkter\" + _imagePath["categoryImagePath"] + "resized/thumbs/" + StripInput(_thumb)
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Format("Add some data on file number: {0}, please? :-)", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working now! I don't know why I didnt think of this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop though the requests' file array.

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in request.Files)
{
    string filename = file.FileName;                        
}
```

Comment: I tryed what u posted Jnoreiga. It comes with an error, saying that it cant resolve symbol "request".

Comment: use a capital R in Request. It's the same object you use in your example for Request.PhysicalApplicationPath